# Azure App Config Feature Flag , Expiration and Hangfire

Tags: azure-app-configuration

I've got an hangfire application which runs some jobs based on scheduled time (recurrence from 30 min to 2 days, depends upon the job).

We want to have them enabled disabled via Azure App Config. and I've managed to register them in this way:

```
   public async Task ScheduleJobsAsync()
   {
       var cronWeekly = GetCronExpression(Cron.Weekly());
       var cronDaily = GetCronExpression(Cron.Daily());
       var cronSyncAvailabilityBokun =
           GetCronExpression(_appSettings.Integrations.Bokun.SyncAvailabilitiesJobCron);
       var cronUnconfirmedInstancePending = GetCronExpression(
           _configuration.GetSection("Hangfire:Crons").GetValue<string>("UnconfirmedInstancesToPending"));
       var cronBokunRequestJob = GetCronExpression(_appSettings.Integrations.Bokun.RequestJobCron);
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cronBokunRequestJob))
       {
           //If we do not have the cron value for bokun requests jobs use every 30 mins by default
           cronBokunRequestJob = "*/30 * * * *";
       }

       var cronNever = Cron.Never();

       //configure background jobs

       await RegisterRecurringJobAsync<IProductHasNoInstancesRemindersJob>(
           "hangfire-recurring_jobs-product_has_no_instances_reminders",
           "ProductHasNoInstancesRemindersJob",
           job => job.Execute(null),
           cronWeekly);

       await RegisterRecurringJobAsync<ITopSellingToursJob>(
           "hangfire-recurring_jobs-top_selling_tours",
           "TopSellingToursJob",
           job => job.Execute(null),
           cronWeekly);
...

 private async Task RegisterRecurringJobAsync<T>(
     string featureFlag,
     string jobName,
     Expression<Action<T>> methodCall,
     string cronExpression)
 {
     string cronExpressionToAssign = string.Empty;

     if (await _featureManager.IsEnabledAsync(featureFlag))
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("Registering job {JobName} with recurring: {CronExpression}", jobName, cronExpression);
         cronExpressionToAssign = cronExpression;
     }
     else
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("Registering job {JobName} with NO EXECUTION. Disabled by Appconfig.", jobName);
         cronExpressionToAssign = Cron.Never();
     }

     RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(methodCall, cronExpressionToAssign);
 }
```

My problem is that once registered I'm unable to unregister them until I restart the application.

My question are the following:

- Is there an event I can attach when the feature flag expire (it' refreshed every 5 min)
- How bad is to have a long running process or a service with a timer that every 5 min checks the flag and call this ScheduleJobsAsync?
- Any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an event I can attach when the feature flag expire (it' refreshed every 5 min)

You could look into push-based refresh as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-dotnet-core-push-refresh?tabs=windowscommandprompt

But your scenario should work with poll-based refresh too (what you currently have). The right settings to get that working are being discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77262366/15560051

> How bad is to have a long running process or a service with a timer that every 5 min checks the flag and call this ScheduleJobsAsync?

You could call `TryRefreshAsync()` on a timer as frequently as you like. But this method only makes a server call to check the feature flag when the configured cache expiration interval has expired. This document has more details about FeatureFlagOptions.CacheExpirationInterval: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core6x

Comment: If you look here you'll see that the reference to IConfigurationRefresher is resolved during the service registration. I've not found a clean way to inject via DI...in my case I need it jn a service not on startup.cs

Comment: Please see this document explaining two ways to get an instance of IConfigurationRefresher (with or without DI): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-dotnet-core?tabs=core6x#activity-driven-configuration-refresh

Comment: This worked!! Thanks ... but can the configuration be refreshed or only the Feature Flag?

Comment: You can refresh any key-values by setting up the `ConfigureRefresh` method. The document linked above is refreshing non-feature flags for example.